# How to create user having member in multiple groups in chef user resource

Tags: resources, chef-infra, recipe

While creating user we can specify group in gid to which he belongs and if this user belongs to multiple groups how can we specify in chef

```
user 'random' do
  supports :manage_home => true
  comment 'Random User'
  uid 1234
  gid 'users'
end
```

If user resource not providing this option how can we achieve in best way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not a user which has multiple groups in fact, it'a group having multiple users (that's managed in `/etc/groups` not in `/etc/passwd`).

the way to achieve that is:

```
user 'random' do
  supports :manage_home => true
  comment 'Random User'
  uid 1234
  gid 'users'
end

%w{group1 group2 group2}.each do |g|
  group g do
    action :modify
    members "random"
    append true
  end
end
```

See the `group` resource [documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_group.html) for more details and available attributes.

Change action to `:create` if the group does not already exists.

Comment: I have followed this approach but i thought while creating the user i can pass multiple groups some thing like below command
"useradd -u 1501 -m -g grp1 -G grp2,grp3 user1"

Comment: @SASI this command will work on two files so in chef point of view this is two different resources, adding the option to do it on user management would just complexify the underlying code with no real benefits at end. Indeed a specialized command could handle this complexity, not a tool like chef aiming at more than just managing users